# Easiest PHP forum to configure to work inside an existing CMS?

Tags: php, authentication, forum

I have been assigned to add a forum into an in-house CMS we have been using for some time.  The system has its own login/user system and an established user database.  Ideally I'd be looking for the easiest forum software to convert to use with our system, but if necassary can rewrite and migrate the user databases to use the forums system.

Does anyone have any experience rolling forum software into their own systems, or recommend forum software that has a clean and concise code-base that is easy to work with?  Any advice is appreciated at this point.

I have been browsing through the [forums section](http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=5&cat=Forums) of [opensourcecms.com](http://opensourcecms.com) but the details available are limited.  Also, this will be running on PHP5, so one that uses some of PHP5's features would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [punBB](http://punbb.informer.com/). It's super simple, with a focus on security. The tag line is 'Because less really is more'.

Comment: After much consideration and tinkering, this BB was the easiest to integrate into our CMS.  It provides an acceptable level of configurability and simplicity (PHPBB had too much complexity for what I needed and Vanilla was a little light on needed features).  Thanks all for the recommendations

Comment: I did the same a few years ago but now with Codoforum there is a better alternative. Just finished the transformation.

Answer (score 3):

[phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) is amazing, its easy to integrate into nearly anything.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia comparison of PHP Forum software packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_(PHP))

Answer (score 1):

Try [Vanilla](http://getvanilla.com/), free open-source and designed to be easily extendable and easy to just use as an add-on inside your application/cms